# Calling a method on a non-existing key within a c++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Quick question. What is the exact behavior if I attempt to call:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, double>> myUMap;
myUMap[5].insert(......);
```

where ...... is a pair, and assuming that myUMap[5] does not exist yet?

I have heard that trying to access an unordered_map with a key that does not exist this way CREATES that key within the unordered map, but in this situation, will this insert run correctly to insert myUMap[5] if it does not exist, or if it does, update myUMap[5]'s map within it?

Comment: yes.  Have you considered trying it?

Comment: @AndyNewman In case of undefined behaviour, things may look like they work, for example, doing `int arr[2]; arr[10]=1;` will seem to initialize (most of the time) the 10-th position in `arr`, even if the array is declared having only 2 elements, so just trying is not always the best way of deciding whether the stuff really works or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line is internally parsed as:

```
(myUMap.operator[](5)).insert(......);
```

where the order of evaluation is left-to-right.

So, you first invoke `operator[](5)` on `myUMap`, which creates an element if the element is not yet present in the map. Therefore, you end up inserting into an element that is already created.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. I suppose I should have specified my question as to specifically what order it ran in in that case.